# Не открываются файлы .csv и .xlsx после записи

Tags: python, csv, словари, python-3.8, xlsx

Есть массив данных, каждый элемент которого является словарём. При попытке записи, программа выполняется, но Excel пишет, что файл битый. Для записи использовал csv и xlwt. Но проблема в том, что даже при попытке записи любого словаря в .csv или .xlsx, файл всё равно разбивается. Пересоздавать файл пробовал. Вот мой код:

```
import csv

my_dict = {'kist': 1, 'dist' : 13}

with open('ctg1.csv', 'w+') as f:
    x = csv.DictWriter(f, my_dict.keys())
    x.writeheader()
    x.writerow(my_dict)
```

Если кто-то сталкивался с подобной проблемой, подскажите, пожалуйста. Версия Python - 3.8.2

Comment: проверил на Python 3.9.2 , все работает

Comment: напишите, пожалуйста, текст ошибки, которая отображается

Comment: Сейчас обновил до 3.10, но всё равно не помогло

Comment: Код ошибки: <_csv.reader object at 0x04030B88>

Comment: попробуйте заменить метод writerow() на writerows(), может поможет, хотя у меня ваш код работает.
Вы запускаете такой же код, как предоставили здесь?

Comment: Трейс ошиби нужно приводить полностью, а не выборочно.